# list of the max and min of the sums

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to list **only** the max and the min of the sums grouped by date where count of the Name is above 2. Below formula works fine to find the max

```
Maks = 
maxx(
SUMMARIZE('Table',
     'Table'[DateStamp],
     "Total",
     CALCULATE(sum('Table'[Value]),
        filter('Table', count('Table'[Name])>2))
        ),[Total]

)
```

sample data

```
DateStamp   Name    Value
7.7.2022    A       55
7.7.2022    B       88
7.7.2022    C       77
8.7.2022    A      125
8.7.2022    B       25
8.7.2022    C       54
9.7.2022    A       61
9.7.2022    C       88
10.7.2022   A       92
10.7.2022   B      113
10.7.2022   C      145
11.7.2022   A      155
11.7.2022   C      255
12.7.2022   A      107
12.7.2022   B      121
12.7.2022   C      167
```

Desired Output is

```
12.07.2022  395
8.07.2022   204
```

Comment: How exactly do you want this 'list' to be output?

Comment: @JosWoolley i made a little change in the sample data and i also added the desired output. thank your for your time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tablo = 

VAR tbl = 
    FILTER(
        SUMMARIZE(ALL('Table'),'Table'[DateStamp])
        ,CALCULATE(
            DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[Name])
            ,ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[DateStamp])
        )>2
    )

VAR tblFiltered =
    FILTER(
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            tbl
            ,"SUM",CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Value]))
        )
        ,OR(
            [SUM]=MAXX(tbl,CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Value])))
            ,[SUM]=MINX(tbl,CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Value])))
        )
    )
RETURN
    SUMX(FILTER(tblFiltered,[DateStamp]=SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[DateStamp])),[SUM])
```

[image]

Comment: hi again @Mik can you please check again. The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12HibfxIx8-bh-oTUUnI20IIu7kneRJ9S/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi @UmutK, I added Concatenatex()

Comment: cant we merge the results as a table ? date column and sum column ?

Comment: do you want a table with 2 rows and one column dat-sum?

Comment: a table with two columns and two rows :)

Comment: If you want to use a table as visual, then add Table[Dates] to rows and the measure as column

Comment: last revision with the sumx return blank 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246945/discussion-between-mik-and-umut-k).

Comment: looks strange, I tested it on your pbix. I added the picture. First it's 'Table'[DateStamp] then measure

Comment: You are wellcome )

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution. I am using DAX.do software to write my dax codes which I think is more efficient. so If you decide to copy and use codes, please do not forget to remove evaluate and give a name to your table, column or whatever....

let's go step by step:
1st Step - Create our table

```
DEFINE
    TABLE Records =
        SELECTCOLUMNS (
            {
                ( dt"2022-07-07", "A", 55 ),
                ( dt"2022-07-07", "A", 55 ),
                ( dt"2022-07-07", "B", 88 ),
                ( dt"2022-07-07", "C", 77 ),
                ( dt"2022-07-08", "A", 125 ),
                ( dt"2022-07-08", "B", 25 ),
                ( dt"2022-07-08", "C", 54 ),
                ( dt"2022-07-09", "A", 61 ),
                ( dt"2022-07-09", "C", 88 ),
                ( dt"2022-07-10", "A", 92 ),
                ( dt"2022-07-10", "B", 113 ),
                ( dt"2022-07-10", "C", 145 ),
                ( dt"2022-07-11", "A", 155 ),
                ( dt"2022-07-11", "C", 255 ),
                ( dt"2022-07-12", "A", 107 ),
                ( dt"2022-07-12", "B", 121 ),
                ( dt"2022-07-12", "C", 167 )
            },
            "DateStamp", [Value1],
            "Name", [Value2],
            "Value", [Value3]
        )
EVALUATE
Records
```

[image]

```
DEFINE 
   MEASURE Records[TotalCount] = COUNT ( Records[Name] )
EVALUATE
ROW("TotalCount",[TotalCount])
```

[image: SSS]

```
EVALUATE

    VAR Maks = MAXX(ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE ( Records, Records[DateStamp]),
             "Total", CALCULATE ( SUM ( Records[Value] ) )
             ),IF([TotalCount]>2,[Total]))
    VAR MinK = MINX (ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE ( Records, Records[DateStamp]),
             "Total", CALCULATE ( SUM ( Records[Value] ) )
             ),IF([TotalCount]>2,[Total]))
    VAR Maks_Date = MAXX(FILTER (ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE ( Records, Records[DateStamp]),
             "Total", CALCULATE ( SUM ( Records[Value] ) )
             ),[Total] = Maks),[DateStamp])
    VAR Min_Date = MINX(FILTER (ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE ( Records, Records[DateStamp]),
             "Total", CALCULATE ( SUM ( Records[Value] ) )
             ),[Total] = MinK),[DateStamp])
    RETURN
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
    {(Maks_Date,Maks),
    (Min_Date,MinK)},
    "MaxDate-MinDate",[Value1],
    "MaxValue-MinValue",[Value2]
    )
```

[image: KXXXXX]

Comment: thank you @ozan sen but expected result is with the related dates... see the last part of the question...

Comment: Hello, Umut. You can check my code for your problem. I hope You know how to use DAX tools like Dax Studio or Dax.do. I used DAX.do to create this. You can think of it as alternative solution. (Salıcakla kal:))

Comment: thank you for your time. but your code gives an error on PI Desktop.  *The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value.* (sen de)

Comment: Hi Umut. Yes, This is in fact not a mistake. It warns you that the expression returns a table. A table is not a measure which returns a scalar value such as calculate, sum/sumx, minx/maxx, rankx, average/averagex etc.. Table functions returns a set of columns and therefore you need 2 options to use them.Either you can use them as table arguments in functions or you will create "new table" command to use them. If you want to know what are the table functions: CALCULATETABLE, SUMMARIZE, FILTER, ADDCOLUMNS, ROW, ALL, VALUES etc... I hope I clarified the point for you.